# Is there a meaning for the Taylor series outside of the radius of convergence?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Is there an interpretation of a Taylor series outside of its radius of convergence?

Does it calculates something or represents something useful?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe there is something in generating functions (google for the generatingfunctionology book)

Comment: Ask Euler.......no seriously.

Comment: @Chrystomath. Do you know his e-mail address ?